# Oracle returns invalid number of rows on json_table

Tags: oracle, json, oracle-19c

When I run following query on Oracle 19, it returns 27 record instead of 30, and I cannot understand why, as I am expecting 30 records:

```
select *
  from json_table('{"values":[[1,120674124,200000000,838654366,564288,100000000,419327183,505596,8400000,335460,10063848,1300680,99335724,168528,0,0,0,0,0],
  [2,126739164,210000000,897502964,544740,105000000,448751482,554376,3780000,358992,4480116,888180,112167972,184788,3780000,0,0,0,0],
  [3,133130616,220500000,970973099,550812,110250000,485486549,622968,3969000,388380,4920396,788340,117714072,207648,3969000,0,0,0,0],
  [4,139806252,231525000,1035145287,567648,115762500,517572643,668448,4167444,414048,5139432,827088,123631896,222804,4167444,0,0,0,0],
  [5,146842056,243101250,1109915313,573948,121550625,554957656,735984,4375812,443964,5555376,691104,129844740,245316,4375812,0,0,0,0],
  [6,154208088,255256312,1165411077,591588,127628156,582705538,790728,4594608,0,1886592,539184,140947212,263568,4594608,0,0,0,0],
  [7,161931576,268019127,1223681630,621504,134009563,611840815,840084,4824336,0,1904796,563484,148073016,280020,4824336,0,0,0,0],
  [8,170041944,281420083,1284865711,652920,140710041,642432855,892428,5065560,0,1871364,586812,155609832,297468,5065560,0,0,0,0],
  [9,178558572,295491087,1349108995,685932,147745543,674554497,947952,5318832,0,1894632,613800,163462620,315972,5318832,0,0,0,0],
  [10,187515948,310265641,1416564445,776052,155132820,708282222,1017432,5584776,0,1885812,643716,171684252,339132,5584776,0,0,0,0],
  [11,196907940,325778923,1487392666,844440,162889461,743696333,1080444,3909336,0,1130172,558972,183160416,360144,5864016,0,0,0,0],
  [12,206770416,342067869,1561762299,978972,171033934,780881149,1147272,4104804,0,867960,578052,192553728,382416,6157212,0,0,0,0],
  [13,217159740,359171262,1639850412,1092876,179585631,819925206,1242744,4310052,0,592632,598344,202443780,414240,6465072,0,0,0,0],
  [14,228045444,377129825,1721842931,1249656,188564912,860921465,1325664,4525548,0,303540,620256,212790564,441888,6788328,0,0,0,0],
  [15,240046536,395986316,1807935075,1401864,197993158,903967537,1434276,4751832,0,0,666948,223643400,478092,7127748,197993158,903967537,406788,135588],
  [16,252098868,415785631,1898331825,1585032,207892815,949165912,1543500,4989420,0,0,707208,234705588,514488,7484136,207892815,949165912,427128,142368],
  [17,264796704,436574912,1993248413,1763736,218287456,996624206,1690344,5238888,0,0,750720,246333264,563436,7858344,218287456,996624206,448488,149484],
  [18,278113452,458403657,2092910831,1977216,229201828,1046455415,1832544,5500836,0,0,796824,258516060,610848,8251260,229201828,1046455415,470904,156960],
  [19,292133640,481323839,2197556370,2186376,240661919,1098778185,2010060,5775876,0,0,846204,271322028,670020,8663820,240661919,1098778185,494448,164808],
  [20,306872916,505390030,2307434187,2389104,252695015,1153717093,2210004,6064680,0,0,898092,284785128,736668,9097020,252695015,1153717093,519168,173052],
  [21,322356636,530659531,2422805893,2606952,265329765,1211402946,2425560,3183948,0,0,818148,302234808,808512,9551868,265329765,1211402946,545136,181704],
  [22,338674188,557192507,2543946186,2866104,278596253,1271973093,2696628,3343152,0,0,872988,317203812,898872,10029456,278596253,1271973093,572388,190788],
  [23,355846248,585052132,2671143492,3039396,292526066,1335571746,3010224,3510312,0,0,928008,333022632,1003404,10530936,292526066,1335571746,601008,200328],
  [24,373890684,614304738,2804700666,3278532,307152369,1402350333,3349824,3685824,0,0,988788,349572228,1116600,11057484,307152369,1402350333,631056,210348],
  [25,392897280,645019974,2944935696,3563520,322509987,1472467848,3751368,3870108,0,0,1056588,366911424,1250448,11610348,322509987,1472467848,662616,220860],
  [26,412920252,677270972,3092182479,3807876,338635486,1546091239,4222512,4063620,0,0,1128252,385171968,1407504,12190872,338635486,1546091239,695736,231912],
  [27,434000436,711134520,3246791602,4068012,355567260,1623395801,4759272,4266804,0,0,1206012,404339484,1586412,12800412,355567260,1623395801,730524,243504],
  [28,456213816,746691246,3409131180,4344924,373345623,1704565590,5382252,4480140,0,0,1291188,424458072,1794072,13440432,373345623,1704565590,767052,255684],
  [29,479662344,784025808,3579587737,4711032,392012904,1789793868,6129744,4704144,0,0,1389096,445498764,2043240,14112456,392012904,1789793868,805404,268464],
  [30,504303660,823227098,3758567122,5028468,411613549,1879283561,6929868,4939356,0,0,1489920,467660448,2309952,14818080,411613549,1879283561,845676,281892]]}',
                   '$.values[*]'
                    columns(x1 number path '$[0]', x2 number path '$[1]', x3 number path '$[2]', x4 number path '$[3]', x5 number path '$[4]',
                            x6 number path '$[5]', x7 number path '$[6]', x8 number path '$[7]', x9 number path '$[8]', x10 number path '$[9]',
                            x11 number path '$[10]', x12 number path '$[11]', x13 number path '$[12]', x14 number path '$[13]', x15 number path '$[14]',
                            x16 number path '$[15]', x17 number path '$[16]', x18 number path '$[17]', x19 number path '$[18]'))
```

if I remove some of rows from middle of the json then last rows (28, 29, and 30) are returned in query result, and as you see all rows have exactly 19 numbers.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

A text literal and *CHAR* types in Oracle - by default - are limited to 4000 bytes (~characters with simple characters/charactersets). Your text literal has 4352 characters, but it gets automatically truncated to 4000 characters, so the last 3 "rows" of your input will be missing/incomplete. Your text literal without the last 3 "rows" has 3876 characters which fits in the limit of 4000 bytes (~characters).

Instead of a simple text literal, you should somehow make this a CLOB, example, below query returns the 30 rows as expected:

```
select *
  from json_table(to_clob('{"values":[[1,120674124,200000000,838654366,564288,100000000,419327183,505596,8400000,335460,10063848,1300680,99335724,168528,0,0,0,0,0],
  [2,126739164,210000000,897502964,544740,105000000,448751482,554376,3780000,358992,4480116,888180,112167972,184788,3780000,0,0,0,0],
  [3,133130616,220500000,970973099,550812,110250000,485486549,622968,3969000,388380,4920396,788340,117714072,207648,3969000,0,0,0,0],
  [4,139806252,231525000,1035145287,567648,115762500,517572643,668448,4167444,414048,5139432,827088,123631896,222804,4167444,0,0,0,0],
  [5,146842056,243101250,1109915313,573948,121550625,554957656,735984,4375812,443964,5555376,691104,129844740,245316,4375812,0,0,0,0],
  [6,154208088,255256312,1165411077,591588,127628156,582705538,790728,4594608,0,1886592,539184,140947212,263568,4594608,0,0,0,0],
  [7,161931576,268019127,1223681630,621504,134009563,611840815,840084,4824336,0,1904796,563484,148073016,280020,4824336,0,0,0,0],
  [8,170041944,281420083,1284865711,652920,140710041,642432855,892428,5065560,0,1871364,586812,155609832,297468,5065560,0,0,0,0],
  [9,178558572,295491087,1349108995,685932,147745543,674554497,947952,5318832,0,1894632,613800,163462620,315972,5318832,0,0,0,0],
  [10,187515948,310265641,1416564445,776052,155132820,708282222,1017432,5584776,0,1885812,643716,171684252,339132,5584776,0,0,0,0],
  [11,196907940,325778923,1487392666,844440,162889461,743696333,1080444,3909336,0,1130172,558972,183160416,360144,5864016,0,0,0,0],
  [12,206770416,342067869,1561762299,978972,171033934,780881149,1147272,4104804,0,867960,578052,192553728,382416,6157212,0,0,0,0],
  [13,217159740,359171262,1639850412,1092876,179585631,819925206,1242744,4310052,0,592632,598344,202443780,414240,6465072,0,0,0,0],
  [14,228045444,377129825,1721842931,1249656,188564912,860921465,1325664,4525548,0,303540,620256,212790564,441888,6788328,0,0,0,0],
  [15,240046536,395986316,1807935075,1401864,197993158,903967537,1434276,4751832,0,0,666948,223643400,478092,7127748,197993158,903967537,406788,135588],
  [16,252098868,415785631,1898331825,1585032,207892815,949165912,1543500,4989420,0,0,707208,234705588,514488,7484136,207892815,949165912,427128,142368],
  [17,264796704,436574912,1993248413,1763736,218287456,996624206,1690344,5238888,0,0,750720,246333264,563436,7858344,218287456,996624206,448488,149484],
  [18,278113452,458403657,2092910831,1977216,229201828,1046455415,1832544,5500836,0,0,796824,258516060,610848,8251260,229201828,1046455415,470904,156960],
  [19,292133640,481323839,2197556370,2186376,240661919,1098778185,2010060,5775876,0,0,846204,271322028,670020,8663820,240661919,1098778185,494448,164808],
  [20,306872916,505390030,2307434187,2389104,252695015,1153717093,2210004,6064680,0,0,898092,284785128,736668,9097020,252695015,1153717093,519168,173052],
  [21,322356636,530659531,2422805893,2606952,265329765,1211402946,2425560,3183948,0,0,818148,302234808,808512,9551868,265329765,1211402946,545136,181704],
  [22,338674188,557192507,2543946186,2866104,278596253,1271973093,2696628,3343152,0,0,872988,317203812,898872,10029456,278596253,1271973093,572388,190788],
  [23,355846248,585052132,2671143492,3039396,292526066,1335571746,3010224,3510312,0,0,928008,333022632,1003404,10530936,292526066,1335571746,601008,200328],
  [24,373890684,614304738,2804700666,3278532,307152369,1402350333,3349824,3685824,0,0,988788,349572228,1116600,11057484,307152369,1402350333,631056,210348],
  [25,392897280,645019974,2944935696,3563520,322509987,1472467848,3751368,3870108,0,0,1056588,366911424,1250448,11610348,322509987,1472467848,662616,220860],
  [26,412920252,677270972,3092182479,3807876,338635486,1546091239,4222512,4063620,0,0,1128252,385171968,1407504,12190872,338635486,1546091239,695736,231912],
  [27,434000436,711134520,3246791602,4068012,355567260,1623395801,4759272,4266804,0,0,1206012,404339484,1586412,12800412,355567260,1623395801,730524,243504],') || to_clob('
  [28,456213816,746691246,3409131180,4344924,373345623,1704565590,5382252,4480140,0,0,1291188,424458072,1794072,13440432,373345623,1704565590,767052,255684],
  [29,479662344,784025808,3579587737,4711032,392012904,1789793868,6129744,4704144,0,0,1389096,445498764,2043240,14112456,392012904,1789793868,805404,268464],
  [30,504303660,823227098,3758567122,5028468,411613549,1879283561,6929868,4939356,0,0,1489920,467660448,2309952,14818080,411613549,1879283561,845676,281892]]}'),
                   '$.values[*]'
                    columns(x1 number path '$[0]', x2 number path '$[1]', x3 number path '$[2]', x4 number path '$[3]', x5 number path '$[4]',
                            x6 number path '$[5]', x7 number path '$[6]', x8 number path '$[7]', x9 number path '$[8]', x10 number path '$[9]',
                            x11 number path '$[10]', x12 number path '$[11]', x13 number path '$[12]', x14 number path '$[13]', x15 number path '$[14]',
                            x16 number path '$[15]', x17 number path '$[16]', x18 number path '$[17]', x19 number path '$[18]'));
```

An alternative is increasing the [MAX_STRING_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/MAX_STRING_SIZE.html), which raises this limit to 32767 bytes, but in my opinion, making your input a CLOB is a more robust solution.